# Magento 2 issues installing sample data on installed Magento 2 website

Tags: magento2

I have installed an instance of Magento 2 and I've SSH'd into my server.

I have updated the composer file by adding this into the require part:

```
"magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "2.1.0",
"magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "2.1.0",
"magento/module-cms-sample-data": "2.1.0",
"magento/module-sales-sample-data": "2.1.0"
```

I then run this:

**bin/magento sampledata:deploy**

But all I've getting is:

**Permission denied**

What do I need to do here to get the sample data installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it as `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy` and make sure you have the correct permissions.